# Questions tagged by skill level

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we want to have questions tagged with the skill level of the person asking it, so others can answer with that audience in mind?  I know it's a bit tricky, since we want to give definitive answers, but the playing strength really does affect the answer that will be most helpful.

Comment: I agree. The skill level of a user really does affect how the answer will be helpful or not.
However, there is a problem we run into; we need duplicate answers that is based on the expertise. So if someone asks something, not only we have to answer their question based on their skill level, but we need to include extra answers that relates to different skill level of others. This is a problem due to obvious reasons.

Comment: This is a good idea, but then that would limit questions too much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who don't know me, I'm Grace Note, a Community Coordinator at Stack Exchange.

Tagging by skill level a different scale and system than normal tagging. Normal tags are designed to categorize what a question is *about*, not what a question *is*. That is, if you look at the tags of a question, you'd be able to understand what the question is covering. So, if there was a question tagged [end-game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-game), then it's pretty clear that the question revolves around the end-game of the match.

When you tag by skill level of the asker, let's say [beginner](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner), then that doesn't actually tell you what the question is about. It gives you warning that the user might not know the high level stuff, but nothing about the topic. For further reading on these kind of tags, [this blog article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) touches the subject primarily.

The ultimate goal of the site is to help everyone at large, not just the original asker - that's why our focus is on the content. Treat the question as independent of the asker's skill level - you want to help as many people who have the same question as possible. These future readers could be of any skill level, so it shouldn't be branded to only a specific section just because the first person to come out with the question. If the asker's skill level is relevant, this should be made clear in the question body. Otherwise, answerers should be aiming to make their answers as universally helpful as possible.

Now, you could judge by the skill level of a particular *strategy*, perhaps. I admit that I'm not an excellent chess player, so I don't know if strategies are particularly divided by skill level. But in that case, you'd still be creating a meaningful classification of questions based on their content. You can group "high level strategy" questions because they're part of some set of high level strategy. But grouping by asker's skill level ends up pretty arbitrary and could span the spectrum of possible topics, rendering it very weak as a filter.

Comment: I'd add to this excellent answer that sometimes — given the skill —, you may want to divide an answer into a **usual answer**, easy to understand, generally the best ; and a higher-level **sometimes answer**, good to know in certain situations, especially for people who already know the basics. That may well be what the OP is after, but in any case, readers can fall in any of these categories and learn something.

Comment: The example I'd give is *castling*. I'm sure many players could still learn about the virtues of castling **early**, usually king-side, be safe, play rooks, etc. That's your plain and good 1400 answer. Apart from that, it's worth mentionning many openings would rather be played castling queen-side, or delaying it to see which side is best, or even centre-castle behind pawns when the occasion arises. That's more of a 1900 answer : most of the time, KISS, but sometimes, it's good to know about other options. I think both answers should be mentionned and labelled as such.

Answer (score 4):

I believe, you can, more or less, deduce a person's skill level by reading his question.
I think taking example from StackOverflow is relevant here: Developers with different skill levels ask questions and depending on how and what question is asked, you know what kind of answer is expected.

Comment: It is not always the case. For example, if a player asks what are some key ideas to keep in mind in a particular opening, the answer can vary quite a bit depending on the player's skill. Such tags would also make it easier to filter the questions.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be a requirement, but when I ask a question, I give my approximate strength (a 1500 rating) to show my "frame of reference."

Comment: I noticed this in your question, and I thought it was very helpful for my (long-winded) answer.  Not sure if that's a field we could add to user profiles?

Comment: What if I have no idea what a 1500 rating is?

Comment: @Soufiane Hassau: Someone with a 1500 rating is a low level club player. Good enough to beat most casual players, but loses to most serious players.